# What is the meaning of this sentence about analytic papers?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, context

> The authors, Yale professors Richard Nelson and Sidney Winter, were best known for a series of intensely analytic papers exploring Schumpeterian theory that even most PhD candidates didn't pretend to understand.

What I got from my research and what I understand from my research is most of the PhD candidates do not understand the theory.

Comment: It means what it says. What don't you understand?

Comment: ELU is not a sentence explanation service. You may want to try this over at [ell.se] (but even there you should point out the specific problem with the sentence you have).

Comment: I think the cited text is *really* dumb! Note that ***pretend*** here can only really be used in its older sense of ***claim***. But so what if this couple of professors wrote some very abstruse papers about Schumpeterian theory? ***Almost all*** PhD candidates wouldn't even know of the *existence* of those papers, so they couldn't *possibly* understand (or *claim* to understand) them. That final assertion should use ***wouldn't***, not ***didn't***, and the reference to claiming / pretending is contextually daft. The honesty / integrity of PhD candidates should be an issue here.

Comment: *...even most PhD candidates **couldn't** pretend to understand, **even if they read them** (which obviously most of them would **not**)*.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the papers in question are so analytic that they are difficult to understand even for most PhD candidates.

Let the presence of *pretend* not confuse you. It is easier to pretend to understand than to understand. So even competent PhD scientists cannot (pretend to) understand them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that might be better answered by an economist.  However, the word 'analytic' is one that can be misunderstood and may not be the best word.

'Analysis' is defined in the Cambridge English Dictionary online:

> the act of studying or examining something in detail, in order to discover or understand more about it, or your opinion and judgment after doing this.

The phrase 'in detail' does not suggest difficulty for understanding mention in the question.  However, what may be difficult to understand are **complex** arguments, heavy use of **abstract** language  and, hardest of all, **complex mathematics**.  These are probably what the writer has in mind.